# Oracle complex sql select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM (UNCOLLECTED)
            FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS LD
           WHERE     LD.COMPANYID = L.COMPANYID
                 AND LD.GROUPID = L.GROUPID
                 AND LD.PERIODID = L.PERIODID
                 AND LD.FORMTYPE IN (1, 2, 3)
```

I need when `L.PERIODID > '2013-2014'` then the `LD.FORMTYPE IN (1,2,3,4)` else `LD.FORMTYPE IN (1,2,3)`

any idea?

Comment: How can a timebased period be greater than '2013-2014', would this equal '-1', does it need to be greater then 2013 or 2014?

Comment: Mathieu the PERIODID is a Varchar column and the values for example is: '2013-2014'
'2014-2015' etc

Comment: I'm not great with oracle, but would this work? `SUM (UNCOLLECTED) FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS LD WHERE LD.COMPANYID = L.COMPANYID AND LD.GROUPID = L.GROUPID AND ((LD.PERIODID = L.PERIODID AND LD.FORMTYPE IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND LD.PERIODID > '2013-2014') OR (LD.PERIODID = L.PERIODID AND LD.FORMTYPE IN (1, 2, 3) AND LD.PERIODID < '2013-2014'))`

Answer (score 1):

This could be the answer

```
SELECT SUM (UNCOLLECTED)
        FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS LD
       WHERE     LD.COMPANYID = L.COMPANYID
             AND LD.GROUPID = L.GROUPID
             AND LD.PERIODID = L.PERIODID
             AND (L.PERIODID > '2013-2014' AND LD.FORMTYPE IN (1, 2, 3) ) 
             OR (L.PERIODID <= '2013-2014' AND LD.FORMTYPE IN (1, 2, 3,4) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is malformed.  You have two table aliases, `L` and `LD`, but `L` is not defined.

Because you intend a `JOIN`, you should be using explicit `JOIN` syntax.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT SUM(UNCOLLECTED)
FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS LD JOIN
     ??? L       -- I don't know what table "L" refers to
     ON LD.COMPANYID = L.COMPANYID AND
        LD.GROUPID = L.GROUPID AND
        LD.PERIODID = L.PERIODID 
WHERE LD.FORMTYPE IN (1, 2, 3) OR
      (LD.FORMTYPE = 4 AND L.PERIODID > '2013-2014')
```